# Continuous headless page automation with IPC

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, ipc, headless, browser-automation

I need to make a headless (for a docker container) app that waits for an external signal and then acts on that signal by clicking on several html elements (selectors, buttons, links) and filling in some input fields. All this can be done using jQuery, I know how to do that.

The app needs to keep the page loaded so it can act immediately, reloading the page every time is taking too long. The whole action of receiving a signal and filling in a form and submit it, should be done under one second.

I made an electron app that does all this but I need to make the app headless so it can be run inside a docker container.

It looks like Phantomjs could do this but I see two problems:

The Phantom script needs to keep the web page loaded as the web page I need to automate is very heavy, it can take more than a minute to load.

The Phantom script needs to be able to receive a signal and report back on the progress. HTTP or file based is too slow, I'd like to use websockets for this communication.

I hope someone can point me to the right tools for this and/or point me to some examples how to achieve this.

I would like to use Javascript, but if there is a perfect solution in an another modern language, I have no problem to use that.

Comment: Do you have empirical evidence that HTTP is too slow? You could just use the [web server module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/).

Comment: The difference between HTTP requests and Websockets is huge. I don't have the numbers at hand anymore but if was like a few hundred times.

Comment: I managed to get it working inside a Docker container using Electron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working inside a Docker container using Electron.